# Ffmpeg fails to encode properly when setting -ar as an option

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a number of videos using Ffmpeg.
Every video I have thrown at it encodes correctly except for 4, At this stage we have encoded over 170 videos without an issue.

I've managed to work out it is failing due to the 4 videos not having an audio frequency in the audio track (Or one not set).

For example, This is the output I get when I inspect a "good" video -

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'good_video.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
Duration: 00:01:57.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2017 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 1705 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 308 kb/s
Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74`
```

And this is the output I get when I inspect a "bad" video -

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bad_video.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
Duration: 00:02:57.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3006 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 2902 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, stereo, s16, 99 kb/s
Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
```

As you can see the "bad" video does not have an audio frequency against it. This appears to be causing my issue.
If I try to encode the "bad" video I get the following error -

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bad_video.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
Duration: 00:02:57.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3006 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 2902 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, stereo, s16, 99 kb/s
Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
[libx264 @ 0x10180d400]using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x10180d400]profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x10180d400]264 - core 114 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=30 keyint_min=16 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1500 ratetol=2.7 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
[libfaac @ 0x10180da00]libfaac doesn't support this output format!
Output #0, mp4, to 'bad_video_encoded.mp4':
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=10-51, 1500 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaac, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I am attempting to encode with the following command -

```
ffmpeg -i bad_video.mov -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 -y bad_video_encoded.mp4
```

I also tried with -

```
ffmpeg -i bad_video.mov -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -g 30 -y bad_video_encoded.mp4
```

But this drops all the frames and only encode the audio.
All of the video is coming from the same source.

Any ideas where we are going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Ffmpeg is having trouble with this, but from using it I know it's quirky.  It looks like some of the metadata is missing from the bad video.  I suggest running [FLVMDI](http://www.buraks.com/flvmdi/) on the file, which will add the necessary metadata, and then rerun Ffmpeg on it.  This step helped me in some cases.